# AS3 Dynamic Sprites/Movie Clips

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, dynamic, sprite

Im having a hard time putting in my head on how would i go at making flash read a xml file (this part I have it going smooth) and then fromt hat elements put on the stage a sprite or a movieclip that is interactive.

To make it clear I want to load and display an image that when you press it it just creates another square beneath it with some text.

I believe I have to interate the xml and then use each of the elements with a class and gettin that object onto the stage.

Im using flash builder and as3 and im looking just for pointing in the rigth direction, of course I apreciate any more elaborate though some head clearing is just as good.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you store in the xml file? Class names to instantiate as MC's, or custom drawing command from which you want to compose MC's?

Comment: Just the name, the text for it, and the url for the image.

Comment: By 'name' you mean class name? Or just the element name or a custom identifier?

Comment: Just like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xml>
 <NODULO>
  <NOME>Hypermedia</NOME>
  <IMGURL>../resources/images/hyper.jpg</IMGURL>
  <TEXT>Some text</TEXT>
  <TAGS>Hypermedia,Communication,Video</TAGS>
 </NODULO>
</xml>

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate on the XML content using the methods as described at http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/XML.html

You would need something like:

```
for (elem in xml.elements("NODULO")) {
    var url: String = elem.IMGURL.text();
    var text: String = elem.TEXT.text();

    var s = new Sprite();
    var ldr = new Loader();
    ldr.load(new URLRequest(url));
    s.addChild(ldr)
    // create TextField, add as child, etc
    root.addChild(s)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your example, just one more thing what should I look at to understand were to take it from there? I mean just general terms for me to research.

Comment: What topic are you interested in? Kirupa forums and Senocular has articles about a wide range of topics (XML, Sprites, mouse listeners), worth looking at. Also, the Adobe Livedocs has nice API description and some examples.

Comment: Im trying to improve my weak as3 code, I know the Kirupa forums and Senocular pages, they are aewsome but im rushing to trying to get this to work so I was aiming for more dead on help. I apreciate yours.  Im more specifically interested in undestanding how to create and add a sprite or movieclip to the stage with a basic interaction. As an off topic do you do freelance? or have a Steam account?

Comment: Well, the (updated) example has a Sprite called s, which is added to the root using root.addChild(s). Basically that is all you need (and adding the image and text as child of s), and maybe keep a reference to s for later use. You can set the s.x, s.y, etc. attributes to control the sprite. See also http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Sprite.html

Comment: Thank you for taking time to guide me in this.